# How to call flask jsonify on an array of key-value pairs

Tags: python, json, flask

I am trying to use jsonify to construct an object from two 1d arrays where the first array (keys) is a list of all the keys, and the second is a list of their respective values (vals). I want to call jsonify({ data : arr }) and get something that looks like this

```
{ data: [
{ key1 : val1 },
{ key2 : val2 }
]}
```

etc. Is there a way to do this? At first I was hoping I could construct arr using something like this:

```
arr = [str(keys[p]) + "=" + str(vals[p]) for p in range(keys.length)]
```

but this obviously doesn't work. Is there a workaround I can use here?

Edit:
Should I try doing something like jsonify({ data : dict }) where dict is a dictionary mapping keys to vals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
data = [ {k:v} for k,v in zip(["key1","key2"],["a","b"]) ]
return jsonify({"data" : data})
```

Comment: This ended up giving me just an array of values where the values were {k:v}. I think my mistake was attempting use an array of key value pairings rather then a nested object which I did by using a dict instead of an array

Comment: I was mistaken this does work I just wanted to be able to get both the key and value so I instead did data = [ { "name" : k, "value" : v } ]